# Why normalized eigen values and eigen vectors can have imaginary number?

Tags: python, numpy

My goal is to prove why normalized eigen values and eigen vectors have imaginary number.

According to [this website](https://byjus.com/jee/normalized-and-decomposition-of-eigenvectors/#:%7E:text=Normalized%20eigenvector%20is%20nothing%20but,the%20vector%20of%20length%20one.): normalized eigen vector is just `an eigen vector divided by the length of the vector`.

I can prove it by comparing the eigen vector that I got manually with `det(A - λ*I) = 0` with the normalized eigen vector from the numpy library.

However, I just don't get it how the numpy library can come up with an imaginary number for the returned eigen values and vectors.

Code

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1,-1],
              [6, 4]])
eigvalues, eigvectors = np.linalg.eig(A)
display(eigvalues, eigvectors)
```

output

```
array([2.5+1.93649167j, 2.5-1.93649167j])
array([[-0.23145502+0.29880715j, -0.23145502-0.29880715j],
       [ 0.9258201 +0.j        ,  0.9258201 -0.j        ]])
```

Isn't the normalized eigen vector formula is `x / np.sqrt(x1^2 + xn^2)`

```
If x = [ -1 ], then normalized x = [ -1 / √3 ]
       [ 2. ]                      [  2 / √3 ]
```

Edit:

I tried to manually calculate the Code.

```
λ = (5 +- i√15) / 2
```

which roughly translate to `2.5 +- 1,93i`. New question: why when I call `eigenvalues.real` it return `[2.5, 2.5]` instead of whatever is the calculation of `2.5 +- 1,93i` is?

Answer (score 1):

So answering your new question so
$$ \lambda = 2.5 \pm i \sqrt{15}$$
have two eigenvalues encoded in the equation is
$  \lambda_1 = 2.5 + i \sqrt{15}$ and $  \lambda_2 = 2.5 - i \sqrt{15}$.
So every complex number consists of two parts real part and an imaginary part.
Notice that the real part for the same for $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ hence when you ask for the real part it returns [2.5, 2.5].

In your case, both eigenvalues are complex hence and the eigenvector which is a tuple $( x_1, x_2)$ where $x_i$ is complex as well, but you are right you divide by the magnitude which is a real number.